# SpringBoot MVC Post Response Entity returning null

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, mockito

Response enitity should be returning a new ResponseEntity with a http status of OK/200. However, during my testing it is returning as null i can see where it is being being set to null but dont understand why or even how. I am sure it's a simple thing i've missed but just cant see it.

As can be seen in the images, the create var is null, however, Mockitio should be setting this to createBlogPostResponse1, so i am not sure why null is being set.

[image: Vars/services instantiated]
[image: create being set to null]

Thanks for any information and help on this.

Test

```
public static ResponseEntity createBlogPostResponse1 = new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);


@Test
public void createNewBlogPost() throws Exception {
    String url = TestHelper.URL + "/blogPost/createNewBlogPost";
    when(postService.createNewBlogPost(blogPost1)).thenReturn(TestHelper.createBlogPostResponse1);
    mockMvc.perform(post(url)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestHelper.asJsonString(blogPost1)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    verify(postService, times(1)).createNewBlogPost(blogPost1);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(postService);
}
```

Controller

```
ResponseEntity create = postService.createNewBlogPost(cleanBlogPost);
```

Service

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity createNewBlogPost(BlogPost createNewBlogPost) {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by JBnizet mockito uses `equals` method internally to match arguments on your mock method invocation. Try overriding `equals` method for `BlogPost` class. If you do not want to override `equals` and you just want to match any method invocation on your mock -  use `any()` matcher :

```
    @Test
    public void createNewBlogPost() throws Exception {
        String url = TestHelper.URL + "/blogPost/createNewBlogPost";
        when(postService.createNewBlogPost(Mockito.any(BlogPost.class))).thenReturn(TestHelper.createBlogPostResponse1);
        mockMvc.perform(post(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestHelper.asJsonString(blogPost1)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        verify(postService, times(1)).createNewBlogPost(Mockito.any(BlogPost.class));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(postService);
    }
```

If you want to gain some basic konwledge about matchers try [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers) tutorial.

Comment: Using eq() is useless. Mockito uses the equals() method to compare arguments by default. No need for a matcher for that.

Comment: Thanks for this i'll look at the tutorial posted, i also updated your answer as the verify in the test also requires your answer to ensure the ocmplete test passes.

Answer (score 1):

As said Mockito relies on `equals()` for argument matching but overriding `equals()` to make a unit test successful is generally not a good idea.  The `equals()` overriding has to have a sense for the concerned class.    If the overriding makes sense, go for it. 
Otherwise here is an alternative where you could use the `any()` matcher combined to a check on the content of the param properties values such as :

```
 when(postService.createNewBlogPost(Mockito.any(BlogPost.class)))
.then( answer -> { 
                   BlogPost post = (BlogPost) invocation.getArguments()[0]; // get the first arg
                   Assert.assertEquals(blogPost1.getFoo(), post.getFoo());
                   Assert.assertEquals(blogPost1.getBar(), post.getBar());
                   return TestHelper.createBlogPostResponse1();
                   });
```

While for assertions without using `equals()` on the object to assert I would prefer AssertJ.